# Python Jira SOAP updateWorklogWithNewRemainingEstimate

Tags: python

Каким образом отредактировать worklog в баге?

`addWorklogAndAutoAdjustRemainingEstimate` работает без проблем, как и удаление. Но вот `update` никак.

```
import SOAPpy
soap = SOAPpy.WSDL.Proxy('https://YOUR.SITE.HERE/jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl')
jirauser = 'login'
passwd = 'pass'
dt_today = SOAPpy.dateTimeType(time.gmtime(int("1"))[:6])
comment = 'testing'
worklog = {'startDate':dt_today, 'timeSpent':'1m', 'comment': comment}
work_log = soap.getWorklogs(auth, newissue['key'])
print str(work_log)
#Добавление работает!!!
soap.addWorklogWithNewRemainingEstimate(auth, newissue['key'], worklog, "1w")
#update выдает ошибку
soap.updateWorklogWithNewRemainingEstimate(auth, [work_log], '55d')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/jira/tst3.py", line 15, in 
>       connect.updateWorklogWithNewRemainingEstimate(auth, [work_log], '55d')
>       File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 547, in **call**
>       File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 569, in __r_call
>       File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 482, in __call
>       SOAPpy.Types.faultType: 
>   class com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteWorklog):
>   : {'hostname':
>   'xxxxxxxxx', 'faultData': : {'exception': None, 'message': 'Bad types (class
>   [Ljava.lang.Object; -> class
>   com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteWorklog)'}}>

[Здесь](https://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/3.13.4-1/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html) был, результата нет!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В операцию `updateWorklogWithNewRemainingEstimate` вторым параметром надо передать объект типа `RemoteWorklog` - а вы что передаете?

Comment: вот как раз это и не понятно...каким образом его туда подкинуть и как

Comment: Ну, в метод добавления вы же его как-то передали! Что вам мешает сделать так же?

Comment: В методе добавления есть параметр как номер баги (newissue['key']), а в параметре updateWorklogWithNewRemainingEstimate его нет. Как изменится именно тот worklog который мне нужен. Это раз.
Далее я понимаю, что здесь нужно передать именно тот объект, который и нужно изменить, но как это сделать, до меня не доходит. Пробовал указывать разными способами

Comment: При чем тут разные способы?! Возьмите любой отладчик и посмотрите, что вы туда передаете на самом деле. Или хотя бы вызов print поставьте. Зачем вы занимаетесь гаданием?

Comment: Кажется разобрался, объект нужно указать:
'worklog = SOAPpy.structType(здесь данные worklog)'
'connect.updateWorklogWithNewRemainingEstimate(auth, worklog)'